# How to return date values from forms

Tags: javascript, html

So, I'm trying to retrieve date information from the user from a form, but I can't manage to retrieve the information.

HTML:

```js
function results() {
  var dateOfWork = document.getElementById('dateInput').value;
  console.log(dateOfWork);
  return dateOfWork;
}
```

```html
<form class="" action="index.html" method="post" onsubmit="return results();">
  <h3>Enter date</h3>
  <input id="dateInput" type="date" name="date" value="">
  <h3>Start and End of Day</h3>
  <div class="clockDiv">
    <p id="startDay">Start</p>
    <p id="endDay">End</p><br>
    <input id="startDayInput" type="time" name="usr_time">
    <input id="endDayInput" type="time" name="usr_time">
  </div>
  <h3>Hourly Wage</h3>
  <input type="number" name="wage" value="">
  <input class="submitbtn" type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit">
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: What is the error?

Answer (score 0):

Use `preventDefault` to stop the form from performing submit request

```js
function results(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var dateOfWork = document.getElementById('dateInput').value;
  console.log(dateOfWork);
  return dateOfWork;
}
```

```html
<form class="" action="index.html" method="post" onsubmit="return results(event);">
  <h3>Enter date</h3>
  <input id="dateInput" type="date" name="date" value="">
  <h3>Start and End of Day</h3>
  <div class="clockDiv">
    <p id="startDay">Start</p>
    <p id="endDay">End</p><br>
    <input id="startDayInput" type="time" name="usr_time">
    <input id="endDayInput" type="time" name="usr_time">
  </div>
  <h3>Hourly Wage</h3>
  <input type="number" name="wage" value="">
  <input class="submitbtn" type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit">
  </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    <script language='JavaScript'>

    function getTime()
    {
    var date = new Date();
    var d = date.getUTCDate();
    var day = (d < 10) ? '0' + d : d;
    var m = date.getUTCMonth() + 1;
    var month = (m < 10) ? '0' + m : m;
    var year = date.getUTCFullYear();
    var h = date.getUTCHours();
    var hour = (h < 10) ? '0' + h : h;
    var mi = date.getUTCMinutes();
    var minute = (mi < 10) ? '0' + mi : mi;
    var sc = date.getUTCSeconds();
    var second = (sc < 10) ? '0' + sc : sc;
    var loctime = month + day + hour + minute + year + "." + second;

    document.getElementById('localTime').value = loctime;
    }
 </script>

    Put This Script into your **result** function and call the function on Submit button
    Hope It will be help Full for you
```